# What is the simplest way to store a value in a Flask app on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, storage

I have a very, very simple Flask app running on Heroku. All it does is listen for an HTTP POST request and, when it gets a properly-formatted request, sends an email.

Sometimes the app receives several requests within a few minutes. When this happens, I do not particularly want to send an email for each request.

I would like to be able to store a timestamp when I send an email in response to a request, and then read that timestamp on subsequent requests to avoid sending the email for, say, an hour.

It seems like I would need to use some storage add-on in Heroku, but all the options seem like complete overkill for this simple task. Is there a simple way to store this timestamp so that it is available to subsequent requests?

Comment: Simplest from a programming perspective? How hard it is to originally code it? How hard it will be to support the code for it? Or maybe from an administration support perspective? How hard will it be to ensure that it is running (if "it" is something that actually "runs")? How hard will it be to backup/restore the database? It is impossible for us to give you a "right" answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store the value of the timestamp of the last email sent in a database or file somewhere.  However, Heroku uses a [read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). There is a temporary file system which can be written to, however files in it are not kept past a single web request, so this precludes persistent storage.

You have several options:

1. Signup for a [Postgresql database](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql) (Free `Hobby Dev` plan for 10K rows of data, you need 1)
2. Signup for [ClearDB](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb) (Free on `Ignite Plan`, up to 5MB of data).
3. Signup for [MongoHQ](https://addons.heroku.com/mongohq) (Free on `MongoHQ Sandbox plan`, up to 250MB of data).
4. possibly use an external service like [Amazon's S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), storing the timestamp of last email in a text file in a bucket. However, you'll incur more incoming and outgoing bandwidth for this.

Personally, i'd go for option 3, but YMMV...

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one client for your application and that client can accept cookies then the simplest way to store a value and recall it later is by writing it to the user session.

For example:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/api', methods = ['POST'])
def handle_post():
    last_email_timestamp = session.get('last_email_timestamp')
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    if last_email_timestamp is None or 
            now - last_email_timestamp > timedelta(hours = 1):
        # send email
        session['last_email_timestamp'] = now
```

Don't forget that you need two conditions for this to work:

- Only one client (since each client gets its own session storage)
- Client must support cookies (Flask writes user sessions as secure cookies)

Answer (score 2):

Redis is by far the easiest option. Install it first (it's free):

```
$ heroku addons:add redistogo:nano
```

Then in your code:

```
import redis

redis.set('last_timestamp', 1234);
last_timestamp = redis.get('last_timestamp;)
```

Note that the nano plan does not include persistent storage, so in the remote case that the server goes down you should plan for now receiving any value.